# IE11 browser is getting crashed when we run a Behat test

Tags: behat

I am currently trying to run Behat on Windows 7 with IE11, but when I start doing it IE browser is crashing.

I have used IE drivers 2.46, 2.53 & 3.0 along with selenium drivers 2.46, 2.53.0 & 2.53.1

Comment: Please add a stack-trace with the error you got, also try with the latest selenium server (3.0) and with the latest IE driver.Without an error we are unable to provide you with a concrete answer.

Comment: Hi Lauda,please find error which I'm facing in following link http://screencast.com/t/KdOtUgwblTT1

Comment: if my answer does not solve your problem please edit your question and add the line that throws this error with the emailpopup id.

Answer (score 0):

Seems you have an Invalid Selector Exception.Maybe it doesn't like the type of quote you are using, try using straight quote instead of curly quote.
Please try one of these selectors (use copy/paste):

css:

```
#emailpopup
```

or xpath:

```
//*[@id='emailpopup']
```